# Output Python script to Discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm trying to add an output from a Python script on another one to my Discord bot.
My first script "clash.py" works and I have a result: a list of items, it works on my OS (Raspbian)
I'd like to put it on Discord when a user send a specific command: !clantest

It works this way for:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'Token'

description = '''Merluchon Bot'''
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description=description)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

bot.command()
async def Mousse(ctx):
    """Cadeau pour le peuple"""
    await ctx.send("https://viesdamelie.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/bain.gif")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

How could I add the result of "clash.py" on a command this way:

```
async def clantest(ctx):
    """Cadeau pour le peuple"""
    await ctx.send("clash.py")
```

Even if I know it is not the way it should be, you see the idea.

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a callable function inside clash.py file

Something like

```
def clash():
    <Code to execute>
```

You can then import your clash.py file at the top of your discord bot file, just like you are currently importing other libs (or files)

Then from inside your clantest bot command you can call your function

```
async def clantest(ctx):
    clash()
    await ctx.send(Whatever your clash function spits out)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! However, in "whatever your clash blabla", what should I put ...? I want the full result of clash.py to appear.

Comment: I don't know what your clash.py file outputs as I haven't seen it.. It's difficult for me to know exactly what to put when I don't know your code

Comment: the outputs look like: 
Name: Nova l Askaa
Trophies: 5084
Tag: #U8PLPCC


Name: Mika fureur
Trophies: 5047
Tag: #88PG2RPGP